# Disabling auto-correct in one language but not the other

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-9, auto-correct

I've setup my phone for two languages: English and Russian; I use both languages for texting and other communication. Although English auto-correct seems OK, the Russian language auto-correct is terrible: it doesn't understand inflections and constantly changes correctly spelled words into completely different ones.

I'd like to turn off Russian language auto-correct. How do I do that? I would prefer to keep English language auto-correct if possible.

The phone is Samsung Galaxy S9+, running Android 9, One UI 1.0.